# query for max date time of initial record set

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I am trying to query a MS SQL db for a record set based in two parameters. One is a GUID the other a date time field where I do not know the maximum date time value or number of the records in the result set.

```
SELECT        ID, code, txtString, msgGUID, tcStat, reportDT
FROM            tblCodes
WHERE        (msgGUID = @msgGUID) AND ....
```

How can I query the largest date time value of this initial set and return only the newest records for the reportDT date time value? Like using MAX in the WHERE clause for the reportDT value.

I am applying this to a vb.net app SQL data source.

Comment: Do you care about time stamp precision? Or do you just want all records for the maximum date in the recordset?

Comment: Just the records with the maximum date of the record set where GUID matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT top (1) with ties
  ID, code, txtString, msgGUID, tcStat, reportDT
FROM            tblCodes
WHERE        (msgGUID = @msgGUID) AND ....
order by reportDT desc;
```

And if you need all records for the whole day (i.e. the time part is irrelevant), you might convert the field into `date` data type in the `order by` section.

Comment: multiple records are returned with the same date time. So I do need multiple records.

Comment: @htm11h, the `top (1) with ties` option will return all rows with the latest report date, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT        ID, code, txtString, msgGUID, tcStat, reportDT FROM   tblCodes 
  WHERE      msgGUID = @msgGUID AND ... AND   reportDT = ( SELECT MAX(reportDT) FROM tblCodes where (msgGUID = @msgGUID) AND ... )
```

Comment: This is returning all null values.

Comment: When I try to remove the FROM clause in the main query it also throws and error.

Comment: This doesn't work because the Sub query is pulling records from other than the set that matches the GUID and the sub query recordset pulls the max date time value with no regard to the guid value which is not in the sub query record set.

Comment: yes you're right i change my answer but why you want to remove FROM clause?

Comment: @bummi then we can have it before reportDT

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a CTE for exact date/time matches like this:

```
;WITH FullSubSet AS (
        SELECT ID, code, txtString, msgGUID, tcStat, reportDT
        FROM tblCodes
        WHERE (msgGUID = @msgGUID) AND ....),

      MaxDateVal AS (
        SELECT MAX(reportDT) AS reportDT FROM FullSubSet)

SELECT ID, code, txtString, msgGUID, tcStat, reportDT
FROM FullSubSet X
WHERE X.reportDT = (SELECT reportDT FROM MaxDateVal)
```

Or to throw out the time stamp (SQL2008+), like this:

```
;WITH FullSubSet AS (
        SELECT ID, code, txtString, msgGUID, tcStat, reportDT
        FROM tblCodes
        WHERE (msgGUID = @msgGUID) AND ....),

      MaxDateVal AS (
        SELECT CONVERT(DATE,MAX(reportDT)) AS reportDT FROM FullSubSet)

SELECT ID, code, txtString, msgGUID, tcStat, reportDT
FROM FullSubSet X
WHERE X.reportDT >= (SELECT reportDT FROM MaxDateVal)
```

Non-CTE Version:

```
SELECT ID, code, txtString, msgGUID, tcStat, reportDT
FROM tblCodes 
WHERE (msgGUID = @msgGUID) AND ....
AND reportDT = (SELECT MAX(reportDT) AS reportDT
                FROM tblCodes 
                WHERE (msgGUID = @msgGUID) AND ....)
```

Comment: I need to do this with a SQL Data Source from vb.net code.

Comment: And you can't specify your own query in .net?

Comment: Well, I am not able to convert your TSQL or CTE.

Comment: Hmm... try removing the leading `;` ?

Comment: I have added a non-cte version, but it will be slower with the sub-select.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   top 1      
         ID, code, txtString, msgGUID, tcStat, reportDT
FROM     tblCodes
WHERE    msgGUID = @msgGUID 
ORDER BY reportDT desc
```